# How could I translate the Italian "non so cosa ho combinato"?

Tags: translation

How could I translate a sentence like the Italian:

> Non so cosa ho combinato!

?

I've translated it into

> I don't know what I've done!

but it seems to me that something's lost in translation.

The sentence could have two meanings:

1. Non so cosa ho combinato (ma sono riuscita a farlo) = I don't know how, but I managed to do it
2. Non so cosa ho combinato (ma ho fatto un disastro) = I don't know how, but I did a mess.

Comment: This question should be asked on [Italian.SE](http://italian.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU isn't a translation service

Comment: You can try to translate it literally, and it will be understood, but it won't sound "natural". You should describe the situation a person would say this—I know, because I'm Italian, but 95% of the users on EL&U aren't. So, describe the situation, and provide a sentence where this expression would fit. For example, I might say "(I don't know what came over me) But I really fucked up" Do you want slang, informal, or a more polite equivalent?

Comment: Exact translation is hard. Word for word can be near impossible because sometimes in other languages 'you just don't say it that way'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you! I'd like to have an informal translation but not vulgar.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Google gives your translation but there is no information about the connotations of 'combinato'. I recommend asking this at 1) a translation site or 2) italian.SE because they are more likely more knowledgable about the nuances of Italian words.

Comment: @Mitch I've already repeated the question also on Italian Language.SE, thank you!

Comment: @Mitch ... and on IL.SE they said the correct place is here :):):)

Comment: @Mari-LouA wasn't just giving you general advice; if you **edit your answer** to reflect her suggestions then your question would be on-topic for this site, and we'll be able to better answer your question. Here are a couple of examples of phrase "translation" questions that are on-topic: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352170/english-equivalent-of-the-portuguese-phrase-this-persons-mood-changes-accordi http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307938/english-equivalent-of-cest-gratuit See if you can edit your answer to more resemble those, and I think you'll get a better response.

Comment: @1006a I tried to edit my post, I don't know if it is enough, thank you!

Comment: *I made a big mess*; *I don't know what I was thinking.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things are untranslatable and this is one of them: there is no way in English to convene the exact same meaning as in Italian...  The only thing that comes a little bit closer then yours is:

> I don't even have a clue how I made it look like that myself!

or go completely the complete other way and use one word instead of trying to translate an Italian idiom and just say:

> [SNAFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNAFU)!

(All depends on the context)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is perfect if I managed to do something and I don't know how, but there is also another meaning: I did a mess and I don't know how! (Maybe I answered by myself with my latter sentence...)

Comment: Ah, my Italian is not good enough to know that!  Editing!  Come back in 5 minutes!

Comment: I accept for the SNAFU :):):)

Comment: Grazie mille!  :) :) :)